# PyFMI FMU-module method get_variable_unit() on constants

Tags: python, fmi, jmodelica

PyFMI FMU-module method get_variable_unit() does not work on constants.

It seems to me that the PyFMI method for FMU-mouldes get_variable_unit()  and _variable_description also handles constants and parameters.

I have made a package M that contains declaration of constants. Try to make it neat and declare both unit and description. When i try to get_model_variable_unit(‘model.variable’) then I get the error message “No unit was found for the variable…”. However it works as expected for get_model_variable_description().

It looks to me as a small bug.

I run JModelica 2.4 installed in the fall, i.e. the recent upgrade of PyFMI to 2.5 that came in December I do not use.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO, do you have a programming related question? Bugs should probably be reported to the authors.

Comment: Hi, Generally there is a grey zone of what is misunderstanding from user and what is a bug, but I admit this looks more like a bug and try to get into contact with the organisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in JModelica.org - see https://trac.jmodelica.org/ticket/5729.